# Java Spring Integration not responding services

Tags: java, jax-rs, spring-integration

In the current project I'm working, we have started to experience issues with the response from the rest service, they are currently not responding after we launch a set of test.

We begin to experience these problems after integration test started.

Our configuration is as follows:
    Spring 3.0.6
    Spring-Integration 2.2.0
    WAS 8.5
    DB2
    jax-rs

This is a sample from our spi files.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<!-- Input and Output Channels TransactionFlow -->
<int:channel id="inputAddPaymentGroupChannel" />

<int:channel id="ouputAddPaymentGroupChannel">
    <int:queue capacity="10" />
</int:channel>

<!-- Internal Steps Channels -->
<int:channel id="sessionAddPaymentGroupChannel" />
<int:channel id="operationAddPaymentGroupChannel" />

<!-- Error channels -->
<int:channel id="errorAddPaymentGroupChannel" />

<!-- Gateway -->
<int:gateway default-reply-timeout="5000" id="AddPaymentGroupGateway" error-channel="errorAddPaymentGroupChannel"
    service-interface="bank.bancamovil.web.business.gateway.AddPaymentGroupGateway"
    default-request-channel="inputAddPaymentGroupChannel"
    default-reply-channel="ouputAddPaymentGroupChannel"  />

<!-- Services activator -->
<int:service-activator input-channel="inputAddPaymentGroupChannel"
    output-channel="sessionAddPaymentGroupChannel" ref="SessionService"
    method="validateSessionUser" />

<!-- Validate Operation -->
<int:service-activator input-channel="sessionAddPaymentGroupChannel"
    output-channel="operationAddPaymentGroupChannel" ref="OperationService" method="validateOperationPayment" />

<int:service-activator input-channel="operationAddPaymentGroupChannel"
output-channel="ouputAddPaymentGroupChannel" ref="AddPaymentGroupService" method="addPaymentGroupService" />

<!-- Error Service activator -->
<int:service-activator input-channel="errorAddPaymentGroupChannel"
    output-channel="ouputAddPaymentGroupChannel" ref="AddPaymentGroupService" method="errorAddPaymentGroup" />

<!-- Beans definition -->
<beans:bean id="SessionService"
    class="bank.bancamovil.web.business.services.device.SessionService" />
<beans:bean id="OperationService"
    class="bank.bancamovil.web.business.services.operation.OperationService" />
<beans:bean id="AddPaymentGroupService"
    class="bank.bancamovil.web.business.services.sharedPayment.AddPaymentGroupService" />
```